# Android and iPhone - Transferring data between two mobile devices over a phone call

Tags: android, iphone, networking, mobile

Is it possible to bind additional data to a native outgoing Android (or iPhone, or any other smart phones) phone call so that the receiver can get the data and do something with it?

I've read about solutions with wifi, bluetooth, 3g/4g connection, but this seems easier to implement if it is at all possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can do that, unless you find a method to transfer data to sound and back, it should not be possible.

Edit: reading this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_services#Data_transmission points me to believe you can do that, but not without rooting the phone. You should read about EDGE and GPRS, and see how they work.

Best of luck doing it, sounds interesting.